# Create one to many table relationship with text input Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables with a one to many relationship - `gratitude_journal_entries` and `self_gratitudes`. Multiple self gratitudes (which are submitted as text entries by the user) can apply to 1 `gratitude_journal_entry`. The data is passed to these two tables via a form.

I am trying to store the self gratitude text entries in an array and then pass these to the `self_gratitude` table along with the foreign key from the `gratitude_journal_entries` table.

The problem I'm having is I'm not sure how to take the input from the array and store this in the `self_gratitude` column.

Here are the columns for the `gratitude_journal_entries` table

[image]

Here are the columns for the `self_gratitudes` table

[image]

Here are the models and the store method in my controller

```
class SelfGratitudes extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'self_gratitudes';
    public $primarykey = 'id';

    public function gratitudeJournalEntries() {
        return $this->belongsTo(GratitudeJournalEntry::class);
    }
}
```

```
class GratitudeJournalEntry extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'gratitude_journal_entries';
    public $primarykey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function selfGratitudes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SelfGratitudes::class);
    }
```

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [

        ]);

        $gj_entry = new GratitudeJournalEntry;
        $gj_entry->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $gj_entry['entry_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i');
        $self_gratitudes = $request->has('self_gratitudes') ? $request->get('self_gratitudes') : [];
        $tj_entry->save();

        $gj_entry->selfGratitudes()->sync($self_gratitudes);


        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'You submitted a new journal entry');
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using select2? https://select2.org/tagging

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep array in database you can use casting on your columns:
[laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

```
class SelfGratitudes extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'self_graitude' => 'array',
    ];

    protected $table = 'self_gratitudes';
    public $primarykey = 'id';

    public function gratitudeJournalEntries() {
        return $this->belongsTo(GratitudeJournalEntry::class);
    }
}
```